XSLT - Output only Header nodes
I have below XML as input:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Header>
        <employeeType>FTE</employeeType>
        <emplID>0001</emplID>
        <emplName>Charlie</emplName>
    </Header>
    <Item>
        <ID>123</ID>
        <Location>TX</Location>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>456</ID>
        <Location>TX</Location>
    </Item>
    <Summary>
        <Total>789</Total>
    </Summary>
</Root>

From here, I only need to output the "Header" node and its children. Output should look like below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Header>
        <employeeType>FTE</employeeType>
        <emplID>0001</emplID>
        <emplName>Charlie</emplName>
    </Header>
</Root>

I used below XSLT:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="Header">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

However, it produces following output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Header>
        FTE
        0001
        Charlie
</Header>


Any pointers on what I am doing wrong.
Tried below XSLT:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="Header">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


You say 'I only need to output the "Header" node and its children' but then the result shows a Root. You do a shallow copy of the Header element and then apply-templates you haven't defined to the attributes and children, what is that supposed to achieve? Match on Root if that is what you need, take the shallow copy of that element and do a deep copy with xsl:copy-of of the Header.

Thank you, that worked.

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Root">
<xsl:copy-of select="Header"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
